# Converting <tr> tag contents to df

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG. I'd like to have the results put into a df, similar to how it appears on the page. I can get the contents of the  tags, but am struggling with how to put the result into a df since all the contents are being moved into a list using the code below.

```
url = 'https://www.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG' 
headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
data = []
for t in soup.select('table'):
    for tr in t.select('tr:has(td)'):
        print(type(tr))
        for span in tr: 
            data.append([d.get_text(strip = True) for d in span])
print(data)
```

I'm sure there's a better way to go about doing this but am struggling to think of a better method than just creating several lists for each column on the page.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
data = []
for t in soup.select('table'):
    for tr in t.select('tr:has(td)'):
        print(type(tr))
        for span in tr: 
            data.append([d.get_text(strip=True) for d in span])
print(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).